# What do we do with articles proposed but not retained for CV Journal Club?

Tags: discussion, journal-club

As the title suggests, what are we supposed to do with articles that were proposed for JC but didn't get enough vote to be retained? Shall we list them in a separate thread (like was done for, e.g. list of freely available datasets)? This might be interesting for two reasons:

1. It will allow us to keep an history of all proposed articles (at term, I can imagine we can organize them by topic);
2. We still have the opportunity to choose one of them in case we are short of ideas for an upcoming JC.

**Edit:**

For the moment, I've listed them in a [public Gist](https://gist.github.com/864758) (BibTeX format).

**Edit2:** by mbq

For even better Web2.0ness, I have made a [public Mendeley group](http://www.mendeley.com/groups/999241/crossvalidated-journal-club/papers/).

Comment: Given no other objections I think this is a good idea. The question then becomes who wants to make the thread?

Comment: @Andy I can. What's your idea about thread format (title + author + review with hyperlinks + summary + flag about whether it has been used or not?)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of just copying the original propositions as they are into the thread. If it is community wiki other members can update with whatever information they want. A more formal format will make it easier to skim through a long list, but that seems like overkill at this point IMO.

Comment: @Andy Sounds good to me (I can still maintain the BibTeX archive). Would be good to know about @mbq's opinion on that.